# How to check for "00" in a hex-coded string in C?

Tags: c, hex

I am trying to take a hex-coded string of values and decode it into normal text. The values within the string are supposed to be separated with a "00" for NULL, so I am trying to check for when "00" comes up and replace that in the decoded string with a "," so I can delimit the values later.

```
int main()
{
    char decoded[256];
    const char hex[] = "746573743d7468697300746573743d74686973";
    strcpy(decoded, "");
    char curr[4];
    char next[2];
    int i = 0;
    while (i+1 < strlen(hex)){
        if((hex[i] == 0) && (hex[i+1] == 0)){
            sprintf(decoded + strlen(decoded), ",");
            i = i+2;
        }
        else{
            strcpy(curr, "");
            strcpy(next, "");
            sprintf(curr, "%c", hex[i]);
            sprintf(next, "%c", hex[i+1]);
            strcat(curr, next);
            int num = (int)strtol(curr, NULL, 16);
            sprintf(decoded + strlen(decoded), "%c", num);
            i = i+2;
        }
    }
    printf("%s", decoded);
    return 0;
}
```

When running this I get:

test=thistest=this

What I want is:

test=this,test=this

I've tried debugging by just checking if hex[i] = 0 and printing something and nothing comes up then either. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This is the third question with similar content I see... I smell homework here...

Comment: There is a difference between `0` and `'0'`

Comment: You don't need to do `strcpy()` before `sprintf()`.

Comment: `sprintf(decoded + strlen(decoded), ",");` can be written more simply as `strcat(decoded, ",");`

Comment: Why don't you check after you decode: `if (num == 0)`

Comment: @Barmar: Or even `decoded[i/2] = ','`, which is O(1) instead of O(n). In general, the use of `sprintf("%c"...)` is a painfully obfuscated way of assigning `char`s.

Comment: @rici That doesn't add a null terminator.

Comment: @barmar: You can add the null terminator at the end of the loop. You only need one.

Comment: `while (i+1 < strlen(hex)){` is going to parse the string on every iteration to get the string length, `strlen` is not cached/remembered. You should be storing this in a local instead of calculating it every single iteration. Same for `strlen(decoded)`, just track this using a local.

Comment: @rici Of course, I'm not trying to redesign his whole thing, just suggesting simplifications to confusing statements.

Comment: @barmar: You don't find that use of `sprintf` confusing?

Comment: @Geoffrey A smart compiler will see that `hex` never changes and cache strlen.

Comment: @rici I do, that's why I suggested strcat. Actually, there's like a dozen ways to improve his code, I didn't feel like posting a complete rewrite.

Comment: @Barmar I think you should check that, how can the compiler know that the result of `strlen`, an external libc function that doesn't return a `const` is going to be the same and "cache" it?

Comment: @Geoffrey `strlen()` comes from the implementation-supplied `<string.h>` header, the implementation can optimize it.

Comment: @Geoffrey: Because `strlen` is a library function with known behaviour and `hex` is `const`. Although in principle, I agree that you shouldn't call `strlen` every time through a loop, GCC will optimise this code. Or at least that part of it.

Comment: @Barmar & rici: No, it won't, see: https://godbolt.org/z/sBW8tC

Comment: @geoffrey: GCC doesn't optimise unless you specify -O something and if you do it does. https://godbolt.org/z/cqeWCi

Comment: @rici Ah, I had missed that and was just checking it now. Yes, you're correct that it does optimize it away, but it's still not something that should be relied on.

Comment: @geoffrey: As I said, I basically agree. And that goes double for hiding the calls to `strlen` inside `strcat`, which won't get optimised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if((hex[i] == 0) && (hex[i+1] == 0)){
```

Your condition is checking for the *value* `0`.  You want to check for the *character* `'0'`:

```
if((hex[i] == '0') && (hex[i+1] == '0')){
```